# Delphi 7, Error when setting Form as a Parent of a BitBtn

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm getting a weird error at compilation when I try to set the Parent property of a BitBtn that's been created at runtime. Using Delphi 7 on Win7 64bit.

> [Error] unitMainForm.pas(70): Incompatible types: 'TWidgetControl' and
>   'TMainForm'

I'm creating the BitBtn at runtime like this:

```
  newButton := TBitBtn.Create(Self);
  newButton.Parent := Self;
```

"Self" here being the form, named "MainForm". 
I'm getting this no matter what I put for a Parent. I've tried putting the current Form, ScrollBox, Panel. The same happens if I try to create a SpeedButton.
The thing is, my code works as expected when I use TButtons, and even TImages, but not with TBitBtns or TSpeedButtons. TButtons and TImages accept the Form as their parent, and show up as expected.
Any ideas?
If it helps, I could provide a sample of the whole code, upon request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing CLX and VCL. Your button is the CLX `TBitBtn`, but your form is a VCL form.

I don't know whether you want your app to be a VCL app or a CLX app, but whichever it is, you need all the parts of your app to come from the same framework.

My guess is that you want a VCL app. And somehow you have used `QButtons`, the CLX unit, rather than `Buttons`, the VCL unit. And that's why you are getting the CLX version of `TBitBtn`.

So, assuming I'm guessing right, simply change `QButtons` to `Buttons` and your code will compile.

Comment: @Bogdan Experience. `TWidgetControl` is from CLX. I know that. And the only way you could not set a CLX button's Parent to a form is if the form was a VCL form rather than a CLX form.

Comment: Thank you. I thought `TWidgetControl` was for both CLX and VCL. It's been a long time since I last time worked with Delphi 7.

Comment: @Bogdan `TWidgetControl` is the CLX direct equivalent to VCL's `TWinControl`.